# Jquery background slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it is possible to change make the div follow the size of its table cell? At the moment I can only display something above another div. This is what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/amosangyongjian/mmqasf5t/54/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".expand").slideDown("slow");
  },function(){
    $(this).find(".expand").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: By the way, you forgot a semicolon after `width: 100%` on your `.expand` CSS. Although adding the semicolon changes the behavior, it is still not what you wanted. See the answer by Roko. Just wanted to say this, though, because probably if you noticed the missing semicolon you would be able to make progress, probably by noticing that you needed a `position: relative;` in the parent element, and so on.

Comment: Yup I changed that too. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
td {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative; /* ADD THIS */
}
.expand {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left:0; width: 100%; height: 100%; /* ADD */
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
  /*height: auto; width: 100%;  REMOVE */
  overflow: hidden;
}
    
.static {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And here's a much cleaner solution with some minor changes in HTML, CSS, jQuery

```js
jQuery(function( $ ) {

  $("td").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".expand").stop().slideToggle("slow");
  });

});
```

```css
td {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
.expand {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.static {
  position:absolute;
  background:yellow;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tableclass">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="static">Hello1</div>
      <div class="expand">Expanded</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="static">Hello2</div>
      <div class="expand">Expanded</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="static">Hello3</div>
      <div class="expand">Expanded</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="static">Hello4</div>
      <div class="expand">Expanded</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and here's another example that uses **no JavaScript at all**
but CSS3 `transition` from `height:0;` to `height:100%;`

```css
td {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
.static {
  position:absolute;
  background:yellow;
  text-align:center;
}
.expand {
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:0;
  background:red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
td:hover .expand{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="tableclass">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="static">Hello1</div>
      <div class="expand">Expanded</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="static">Hello2</div>
      <div class="expand">Expanded</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="static">Hello3</div>
      <div class="expand">Expanded</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="static">Hello4</div>
      <div class="expand">Expanded</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed

Comment: Sorry is it possible to center the text for the Hello as well? I can't seem to align it to the center